# Sorted CIDR in a data frame, check for literal equivalence and overlapping for each element

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, ip, cidr

I do have two sorted data set(IP ranges in CIDR) uploaded in a dataframe as shown below. I need
to compare each element in the first column against the entire elements in the second column
in two ways. One, literal equivalence, and two if they overlap, if none of those conditions
are satisfied, I take note of that particular CIDR. Am avoiding using for-loop because
I feel it won't be efficient. Is there a way that would get the CIDRs that are unique -i.e they not
not overlapping and not appearing in both columns. Snippet of the data frame

[image]

Comment: Please a version of your dataframe that can be copied into a text editor

Comment: Is there a reason that the two lists are of the same length? Without information about this constraint, it's difficult to understand how one might take advantage of the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that will get this done:

```
# re-create data from example, with an extra network IP to illustrate process
import pandas as pd
common_list = ['10.0.0.' + str(x) + '/30' for x in (list(range(128, 176+1, 4)) + [248, 252])]
network_series = pd.Series(common_list + ['10.0.8.0/24', '10.0.9.0/24', '192.168.0.0/16'], name='network')
summary_series = pd.Series(['10.0.0.0/8'] + common_list + ['10.0.10.0/24'], name='summary')
# the above series come from the DF in the example (+tweak)

# pre-process: convert the lists to sets of ip_network
# note that ip_network is hashable, so we can do this without problems
from ipaddress import ip_network
network_ip_set = set([ip_network(n) for n in network_series])
summary_ip_set = set([ip_network(s) for s in summary_series])

# remove the identically common elements from the first list, since they don't qualify
candidate_newtork_ip_set = network_ip_set - summary_ip_set

# outer-product set-comprehension with overlap check.
# identify overlapping elements to remove from the candidate list later.
overlapping_network_ip_set = {n for n in candidate_newtork_ip_set for s in summary_ip_set if n.overlaps(s)}

# finally, remove the bad elements from the candidate set and report the result
result = [str(n) for n in (candidate_newtork_ip_set - overlapping_network_ip_set)]
print(result)
```

**Explanation**

Assuming that your inputs are strings representing valid IP ranges, start out by converting them to `set`s of `ip_network` objects from Python's `ipaddress` module. Note that `ip_network` is a hashable type, so they can be stored in sets and conform to standard set operations (intersection, union, difference, etc.).

Next, remove the identically common elements from the first list since we're sure they don't qualify.

Having done this, and with `M` elements left in the first list and `N` in the second, we can now do `M×N` overlap checks, and retain the elements in the first list that don't overlap with any element in the second.

It might be possible to reduce the complexity if more information about the input sorting is available.